Swap in matic without gas
How to swap WETH(POLYGON) or ETH(ETHERIUM) to MATIC with empty balance on polygon (no money for gas in matic). Current gas fee 41 usdt but i need only 0.01 - 0.02 MATIC. Thank you
0x4c13dfa4Fd6D0dfe63c73c3da0660404a2e42195

To directly bridge into the gas token. Polygon suggest:

Powered by 0x, Refuel Gas allows you to purchase MATIC or ETH for gas.


https://portal.polygon.technology/bridge

Stargate or Sushi xSwap would be another option for that.

https://stargate.finance/
https://www.sushi.com/swap/cross-chain

Alternatively they have a faucet that should just require discord authentication, and may give enough to swap previously bridged assets..

https://faucet.polygon.technology/

